# Creating a Domain Behind a Router

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

My current network configuration includes multiple computers in addition to a server that are all currently connected to a router. Is there anything in addition to setting up a Domain Controller that requires one to configure a router so that a Windows Domain will operate successfully or is the router independent of the situation?

If configuration is necessary, how would one go about doing so?

Comment: I'm sorry but your question doesn't make any sense. Could you expand on your question as well as explain how you think domains and routers are related to each other?

Comment: @joeqwerty Clarified question with specific items. Does this help?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to host a web-facing Internet domain or that you want to create an active directory domain? They're two totally unrelated things.

Comment: @MDMarra Edited that in just before your comment. Tags might help in answering as well.

Comment: I read your edit. It doesn't address my question. The tags say active directory, but your question doesn't make any sense in an AD context.

Comment: Seeing your edits - Creating an AD domain isn't related to your router in any way that's relevant to AD.

Comment: @joeqwerty Okay hopefully my point is coming across. Edited once more. :)

Comment: Your router has nothing to do with AD so long as the clients can reach the DC.

Comment: @Shaz - Seeing your additional edit. - Your router is independent of your AD implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This technet wiki](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12370.step-by-step-guide-for-setting-up-windows-server-2012-domain-controller.aspx) has a step-by-step guide for creating an AD domain using Windows Server 2012.

Your router configuration has nothing to do with this.